# Creating threads from a list of tasks

Tags: rust

I try to set up my first-ever thread machine and ran into the following issue.

We have this state:

```
use std::{thread, sync::mpsc};



fn main() {
    let tasks = vec![String::from("task1"), String::from("task2")];

    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let tx1 = tx.clone();

    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        for i in 0..(tasks.len()/2 - 1){
            let send = format!("{}, {}", tasks[i], String::from("done"));
            tx.send(send).unwrap();

        }
    });

    for i in tasks.len()/2..tasks.len() - 1 {
        let send = format!("{}, {}", tasks[i], String::from("done"));
        tx1.send(send).unwrap();
    }

    handle.join().unwrap();

    for string in rx {
        println!("{}", string);
    }

}
```

I try to set up parallel threads, which do something with the strings in the vector. They should work and send until the whole vector is covered. The vector has reliable 100 entries.

The corresponding error message:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `tasks`
  --> src/main.rs:19:14
   |
6  |     let tasks = vec![String::from("task1"), String::from("task2")];
   |         ----- move occurs because `tasks` has type `Vec<String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
11 |     let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
   |                                ------- value moved into closure here
12 |         for i in 0..(tasks.len()/2 - 1){
   |                      ----- variable moved due to use in closure
...
19 |     for i in tasks.len()/2..tasks.len() - 1 {
   |              ^^^^^ value borrowed here after move

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

It seems like I really do not understand how to set up parallel threads and how to treat channels together with threads and a list of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler indicates, the problem is that you moved the vector of tasks when spawning a thread, and then you try to borrow the vector from the main thread while it was already moved.

The problem you need to solve here is how to share the vectors' ownership between the main thread and the spawned thread. One way to do it is to use `Arc`.

Based on your code, I have wrote an example,

```rust
use std::{thread, sync::mpsc};
use std::sync::Arc;


fn main() {
    let tasks = Arc::new(vec![String::from("task1"), String::from("task2")]);
    let tasks_arc_clone = Arc::clone(&tasks);

    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let tx1 = tx.clone();
    
    let mid_idx = tasks.len() / 2 - 1;

    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        for i in 0..mid_idx {
            let send = format!("{}, {}", tasks_arc_clone[i], String::from("done"));
            tx.send(send).unwrap();

        }
    });

    for i in mid_idx..tasks.len() {
        let send = format!("{}, {}", tasks[i], String::from("done"));
        tx1.send(send).unwrap();
    }

    drop(tx1);

    for string in rx {
        println!("{}", string);
    }
    
    handle.join().unwrap()
}
```

Rust [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4e28457aabafc38c391f7625a7131d7b), in case you want to play with it.